# How to store the values from a list in WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I need to store the values from a list and then need to select a value from the list which matches the value of a variable declared.
I'm using cucumber framework and Java
I have already found the element from which the values needs to be stored.
I'm attaching the HTML tag image.
I'm not so acquainted with Java.
[image]

Comment: Can you give an example? What would contain a variable and what would you like to take from the list according to that variable value?

Comment: You need to improve your Java skills. Problem has nothing to to do with webdriver, and you would not use webdriver to store values: webdriver is a library which java uses to automate the browser. IOW this is a java question, not a webdriver question.

Comment: +1, Peter I observed the same thing in other multiple questions where people mix language level issues with automation framework/library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
    WebElement ul= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='addressListItems']"));//xpath of ul
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    List<WebElement> allOptions= ul.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
    for(WebElement selectLi: allOptions)
    {
        if(selectLi.getText().equals(data)) {
            selectLi.click();
        }
    }
```

Learn List of WebElement concept